# Configuring Nginx for WordPress

Tags: nginx, php, centos7

I am very new to Linux. I have a VPS with Vultr and want to move from Apache to Nginx.

I am trying to following this guide, but when running this:

```
yum install php php-mysql php-fpm
```

I am getting this error:

```
[root@j_server ~]# yum install php php-mysql php-fpm
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: mirrors.clouvider.net
* epel: mirror.netweaver.uk
* extras: mirrors.clouvider.net
* ius: lon.mirror.rackspace.com
* updates: mirror.sov.uk.goscomb.net
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 for package: php-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 for package: php-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
---> Package php-fpm.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 for package: php-mysql-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.4.16-43.el7_4.1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: mod_php70u-7.0.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php < 7.0.29
--> Processing Conflict: mod_php70u-7.0.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts mod_php < 7.0.29
--> Processing Conflict: php70u-cli-7.0.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-cli < 7.0.29
--> Processing Conflict: php70u-common-7.0.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 7.0.29
--> Processing Conflict: php70u-pdo-7.0.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64 conflicts php-pdo < 7.0.29
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: mod_php70u conflicts with php-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
Error: php70u-cli conflicts with php-cli-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
Error: php70u-common conflicts with php-common-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
Error: php70u-pdo conflicts with php-pdo-5.4.16-43.el7_4.1.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried Googling, but couldn't find a solution. The error says there is a conflict, but when I ran:

```
rpm -qa | grep php
```

All I got was this:

```
[root@j_server ~]# rpm -qa | grep php
php70u-common-7.0.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
mod_php70u-7.0.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
php70u-pdo-7.0.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
php70u-cli-7.0.29-1.ius.centos7.x86_64
```

Comment: First glance, looks like a conflict between PHP versions. The "php" package is probably PHP 5.4, you need to work out the PHP7 package names. Use Google to find a Wordpress guide that uses yum (Centos / Amazon Linux) and PHP 7.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I got passed those error by manually removing all php related packages, then running the commands again, but now when I run `nginx -t` I get: `nginx: [emerg] module "/usr/lib64/nginx/modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so" version 1012002 instead of 1014000 in /usr/share/nginx/modules/mod-http-geoip.conf:1`

Comment: I suspect you need a more modern tutorial. Installing Nginx / PHP is typically fairly trivial.

Comment: can you link me to any that you know are up to date?

Comment: Get rid of that IUS crap. Always use the remi repo for PHP.

Comment: Sorry but you'll have to find your own tutorial, I haven't needed one.